# Show different windows when editing a form vs editing a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When in Visual Studio 2010 is it possible to have presets on window layouts?  I would like to have VS auto show/hide windows depending on what type of document I'm viewing at the time.  For example...

### When editing a `FORM` I want to see the following windows in the IDE

- Solution Explorer
- Toolbox
- Properties

### When editing a `CLASS` I want to see the following windows in the IDE

- Solution Explorer
- Find and Replace

It would also be acceptable to simply have a quick way to change layouts manually instead of it happening automatically based on the type of document I'm viewing at the time.

Comment: Very hard to see why you can't arrange your windows to get this layout.  Find&Replace is however rather volatile, it is designed to get out of the way easily.  To be quickly resurrected with a shortcut keystroke.

Comment: The question is, can you make this happen automatically when switching between "tabs" in the IDE?  I'm pretty sure the answer is: No, not without writing an extension of sorts.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, thanks for understanding the question.  Do you happen to know of an extension like that?  I just hate all the unneeded windows open when I'm working on a class and they are a must when designing a form.  I would be VERY happy if there was a presets manager for the windows!  Then I could just switch from Layout A to layout B as I need them...

Comment: I've never seen one, I would also be interested in something like that, but I suspect it would be a bit of a performance drag on the IDE.

Comment: @CodingGorilla thanks for the advice!  I ended up coming up with a solution in case you're interested.  It works PERFECTLY!

Comment: @CodingGorilla Sorry for the poorly asked question.  I have edited it to make more sense.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry to you as well about the bad question.  I just have to switch back and forth constantly to have more room and a better layout when going from design to code views.  Not to mention on different devices (PC, laptop, etc).  I have edited the question to be more clear also.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer after some helpful feedback from CodingGorilla!

### Solution:

Install the `Layouts O Rama` Visual Studio extension.
[image]

### How To Install The Extension:

1. Open up `Tools` -> `Extension Manager`
2. On the left, click on `Online Gallery`
3. On the top right click in the `Search Online Gallery` text box.
4. Search for `Layouts O Rama`
5. Click install
6. Restart Visual Studio

The new options will be located under the `Tools` menu.
[image]

### How To Assign Shortcuts To Access The Layouts Quickly

Once you set all your layouts up with `Save Windows Layout` for each layout, you can then assign some keyboard shortcuts to each layout for quick access!

1. Open `Tools` -> `Layouts O Rama Window`
2. Click the little lightning bolt at the top
3. Setup your layouts for quick access.  For me personally I just set `1` to my layout `Code Layout` and `2` to my layout `Design Layout`
4. Close the `Layouts O Rama Window` window
5. Open `Tools` -> `Options`
6. Find `Enviroment` -> `Keyboard` on the left side
7. In the `Show commands containing:` text box to the right type `windowslayout`
8. For each `Tools.LoadWindowsLayout` (0-9) do the following steps 9-12
9. Click on `Tools.LoadWindowsLayout0` (`0` should be the number layout you are working with ex: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9)
10. Click in the `Press shortcut keys:` text box
11. Press `Ctrl+W` then press `0` (`0` should be the number layout you are working with ex: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9)
12. Click the `Assign` button

[image]

Comment: Link to extension in VS gallery: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c  It's available for all versions of VS since 2010.